# Emacs, convert "M-x command <ret> <tab>" to single command

Tags: emacs

I've been spoiled by my recent dip into Vim. It is easy to make a macro there that will combine key strokes that result in a prompt. For instance the following, with `,c`, I get a prompt for color schemes, as well as the list generated by typing `Tab`.

```
" colorscheme switcher
nnoremap <leader>c :colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
```

Now I realize, I'm not sure how to do it Emacs. Here is a naive attempt at how the code would go,

```
(defun load-theme-prompt ()
       (interactive)
       (load-theme)
       (kbd "<tab>"))
```

Of course that won't work, and I did try recording a macro and inserting (even tried `kmacro`), but it complained about `'` not being a theme, but I didn't see any quotes in the macro output.

That is, I tried to record `M-x load-theme <RET> <TAB>`, and insert to buffer, but the function does not work, even if I trim parts off.

Here is the recorded macro that does not work,

```
(fset 'load-theme-prompt
   [?\M-x ?l ?o ?a ?d tab ?t ?h tab return tab])
```

Trying `M-x load-theme-prompt` gives me the following error,

```
load-theme: Invalid theme name `'
```

[image: load-theme-prompt]

With lawlist's comments, I've taken another shot, but now I get wrong number of arguments:

```
(defun load-theme-prompt ()
  (interactive 
   (list
    (intern (completing-read "Load custom theme: "
                             (mapcar 'symbol-name
                                     (custom-available-themes))))
   nil nil))
  (load-theme "%s")
  )
```

I've tried moving the `nil nil` into `(load-theme "%s" nil nil)` but still not working.

Comment: Macros are nifty, but a function that does everything is usually the better way to go if you will be using it fairly often.  Is there a specific theme name you want to load, or would you rather see a list of themes to choose from each time you run your custom function or macro, or would you prefer a choice of just a few pre-selected themes -- e.g., a b or c?

Comment: I may be being overly idealist, but I thought it would be nice if it called up the same screen that load-theme and tab completion would. Perhaps this is actually harder? I guess I'm hoping for either a very minimal, easy-to-recycle function, and/or faithfulness to the original behavior. Above is a screenshot of what `M-x load-theme <RET> <TAB>` gives.

Comment: The function `load-theme` (in the library `custom.el`) uses a function called `completing-read` which in turn uses `(mapcar 'symbol-name (custom-available-themes))`.  The tab key is what triggers the list of available themes.  Perhaps someone else can suggest a better method, but the only one I see off the bat is rewriting the function `load-theme` to force `(minibuffer-complete)` to activate.  You essentially want to insert `(minibuffer-complete)` near the beginning of the function `load-theme` and I don't know how to do that without a re-write.

Comment: @lawlist Does the same go for calling the function with no argument? For instance, what also doesn't work is `M-: M-( load-theme RET`.

Comment: `load-theme` has a *mandatory* argument of the theme name when not called interactively.  When called interactively, the user has an option to select the theme name.  The function contains an `error` message if a valid theme is not selected.  Try out `M-x find-function RET load-theme RET` so you have a better idea of what is at issue.

Comment: @lawlist, I added another try, I feel like I'm closer (though without your `(minibuffer-complete)` yet), but I'm getting a wrong number of arguments. Essentially, I yanked the interactive from the original `load-theme` function.

Comment: Please note my edit, which actually addresses your question, unlike before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at your code, you should probably change it to something like this:

```
(defun load-theme-prompt (name arg2 arg3)
  (interactive 
   (list
    (intern (completing-read "Load custom theme: "
                             (mapcar 'symbol-name
                                     (custom-available-themes))))
   nil nil))
  (load-theme name arg2 arg3))
```

`(interactive ...)` passes arguments to the function, but your function takes no arguments.
Also, you don't really want to pass a literal `"%s"` to load-theme.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track, but it activates when activating `execute-extended-command`.  Can you revise it a bit please so that nothing happens when using `M-x . . . .`  Thanks.

Comment: When do you think the function should be activated, then?

Comment: I think perhaps `execute-extended-command` causes your proposed solution to activate.  The problem is that `completing-read` is used by a zillion other functions, so it is difficult to `defadvice` it without having unintended side-effects.

Comment: If the OP wants this behavior, he could do an around advise of `execute-extended-command`, to activate, then deactivate the `completing-read` advice. But I'm not sure why you think this is better.

Comment: I'm only suggesting that any solution should be limited to `load-theme`, without having unintended side-effects on other functions that rely upon the default behavior of `completing-read`.  Before dinner tonight I was playing around with `(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Completions*" (display-completion-list (all-completions "" (custom-available-themes)) (buffer-string)))` -- working that into a modified function of `load-theme` would probably be better than defadvicing `completing-read`, but I had trouble figuring out how to make it insert the result into the minibuffer intstead of the buffer.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I am actually showing the OP how to get this behavior globally. If you just want something for `load-theme`, it is better to define a custom function for it (it also suffices to replace `execute-extended-command` with `load-theme` in my edit above. Regarding inserting results that are disposable, you should probably use `(with-temporary-buffer ...)` as I did above.